# Unity Unable to Open Package Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm running 2020.1.10f1 on Windows 10. Whenever I click Window -> Package Manager I get the following error. I'm getting the same error on our Mac as well. I tried resetting the layout back to default but it didn't help.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.PackageManager.UI.PackageManagerWindow.SelectPackageAndFilter (System.String packageIdOrDisplayName, System.Nullable`1[T] filterTab, System.Boolean refresh, System.String searchText) (at <3037c1046402403280ab8b0782ca806f>:0)
UnityEditor.PackageManager.UI.PackageManagerWindow.OpenPackageManager (System.String packageNameOrDisplayName) (at <3037c1046402403280ab8b0782ca806f>:0)
UnityEditor.PackageManager.UI.Window.Open (System.String packageNameOrDisplayName) (at <3037c1046402403280ab8b0782ca806f>:0)
UnityEditor.PackageManager.UI.Window.ShowPackageManagerWindow (UnityEditor.MenuCommand item) (at <3037c1046402403280ab8b0782ca806f>:0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a mismatch in versions of the external-dependency-manager. I upgraded to the latest one and I was able to open the Package Manager.

Comment: How did you upgrade to the latest one?

Comment: I downloaded the latest external-dependency-manager. I don't remember the link though. Do a search for it.